# Problem 12 from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

If $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are two subgroups of finite index in $G$, prove that $H\cap K$ is of finite index in $G$. Find an upper bound for the index of $H\cap K$ in $G$?

**My solution:**

**Finite case:** Let's consider the case when $|G|<\infty$ then it is easy to establish via Lagrange's theorem that $$i_G(H\cap K)=\dfrac{|G|}{|H\cap K|}=\dfrac{|G|}{|H|}\cdot \dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}=i_G(H)\cdot\dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}=i_G(H)\cdot \dfrac{|G|}{|K|}\cdot \dfrac{|K|}{|G|}\cdot \cdot \dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}=i_G(H)i_G(K)\cdot \dfrac{|K||H|}{|G||H\cap K|}=i_G(H)i_G(K)\cdot \dfrac{|KH|}{|G|}\leqslant i_G(H)i_G(K)$$
In the last line I've used the formula $|HK|=\dfrac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ and that $KH\subset G$.

2. Let's consider the case when $|G|=\infty$ and suppose that $i_G(H)=p,\  i_G(K)=r$

For any $g\in G$ it is true that $(H\cap K)g\subset (Hg)\cap (Kg)$. Since subgroups $H$ and $K$ has $p$ and $r$ right cosets, respectively. Then then number of right cosets of $H\cap K$ less or equal than $rp$.

So in both cases we derive that $i_G(H\cap K)\leqslant i_G(H)i_G(K)$.

Probably this problem is already exists in forum but i would to know is my second part is true? However, this solution is quite short.

**EDIT:** The set $H$ has $p$ cosets, namely $\{H_1, H_2,\dots, H_p\}$ and the set $K$ has $r$ cosets, namely $\{K_1, K_2,\dots, K_r\}$. Above i have shown that exists function $\phi: (H\cap K)g \to (Hg, Kg)$. This function takes at most $pr$ values. If we show that $\phi$ is injective then the number right cosets is also $\leqslant pr$.

Suppose that $g_1$ and $g_2$ such that $(H\cap K)g_1\subset H_1\cap K_1$ (WLOG) and $(H\cap K)g_2\subset H_1\cap K_1$. If $x\in (H\cap K)g_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in (Hg_1)\cap (Kg_1)$ then $Hg_1=H_1$ and $Kg_1=K_1$. Thus it follows that $(H\cap K)g_1=(H\cap K)g_2$. Sorry but i did not write in detail.

Comment: Incomplete. You proved that there is a function from cosets of $H \cap K$ to pairs of cosets and $H$ and $K$, given by sending $(H \cap K)g$ to the pair of cosets that contain $(H \cap K)g$, specifically $Hg$ and $Kg$. You are right, that there are $rp$ pairs of cosets of $H$ and $K$. But you still must prove that the function is one-to-one. Suppose $(H \cap K)g_1$ and $(H \cap K)g_2$ are both contained in $Hy \cap Kz$ for the same $y,z$. Can you prove $(H \cap K)g_1 = (H \cap K)g_2$? Then you will know that you have a one-to-one function. (It is not difficult.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler, Why the condition of "injectivity" is important? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: If you want to prove set $A$ has size less than or equal to the size of set $B$, $|A| \leq |B|$, then it's not enough to just make a function $A \to B$. There can be functions from $A$ to $B$, even if $|A| > |B|$. But if you prove that there is an *injective* function from $A$ to $B$ then it proves that $|A| \leq |B|$. In this exercise your goal is to prove that $|G/H \cap K| \leq |G/H \times G/K|$. You have a function $f : G/H \cap K \to G/H \times G/K$, and you saw that $G/H \times G/K$ has $rp$ elements. That is not enough, you should prove $f$ is injective (or choose a different strategy).

Comment: @ZachTeitler, please take a look at my EDIT. I have added some notes. I guess it is correct

Answer (score 1):

After the edit and the proof of injectivity the proof seems fine, but it's possible to get an even shorter proof. Namely we have that $H \cap K \le H$, so:

$$[G:(H \cap K)] = [G:H][H:(H \cap K)] = [G:H][HK:K] \le [G:H][G:K]$$

Note that the well-known fact $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$ is just a corollary for finite case of our punch-line $[HK:K] = [H:(H \cap K)]$. In fact in the proof for the finite case one first proves the infinite one. Anyway it holds as:

$$(h_1k_1)K = (h_2k_2)K \iff h_1^{-1}h_2 \in K \iff h_1^{-1}h_2 \in K \cap H \iff h_1(K \cap H) = h_2(K \cap H)$$

Moreover note that above bound is the best possible, as for example we have equality for the case $G = H \times K$.